# SOSL - binding a list of IDs to an IN clause

Tags: sosl

SOSL is returning different results when using a bind variable. For example, the following code snippet returns fewer results when a bind variable is used and returns more results when the bind variable is actually replaced with hardcoded values (See commented line). Has anyone encountered similar behavior?

```
    List<AVTRRT__Candidate_to_Hotbook__c> candidateToHotbooks = [
        SELECT AVTRRT__Candidate__c
        FROM AVTRRT__Candidate_to_Hotbook__c
        WHERE AVTRRT__Hotbook__c = 'a2t5w0000040F9FAAU'
    ];
    List<Id> hotbookCandidateIds = new List<Id>();
    
    for (AVTRRT__Candidate_to_Hotbook__c candidateToHotbook : candidateToHotbooks) {
        hotbookCandidateIds.add(candidateToHotbook.AVTRRT__Candidate__c);
    }
    
    List<List<SObject>> s = [ FIND 'VENDOR' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact (Id,Email WHERE Id IN :hotbookCandidateIds  ORDER BY Email DESC )];

//List<List<SObject>> s = [ FIND 'Vendor*' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact (Id,Email WHERE Id IN ('0035w00003NZ4h3AAD','0035w00003NZ5MOAA1','......') ORDER BY EMAIL DESC)];

    system.debug('@@@'+s);
    List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();
    conList  = ((List<SObject>)s[0]);
    
    for(Contact con: conList){
        System.debug('@@@@'+ con);
    }
```

Comment: Apex debug log should show the result of evaluating the query. From there you'd have enough info to say whether this is a SF bug or an issue with your code or data.

Comment: One thing that is worth keeping in mind is that the mechanism serving SOSL under the hood is the same that provides search results in the search bar and is liable to change over time. That's why when you need to test code that runs SOSL there's a method for mocking your SOSL return results.